# Laravel query builder whereIn doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

I have below Models and I need to get an array of `district_id` without field name. (like, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`)

`Province [id, description]`

`District [id, description, province_id]`

```
$province_arr = DB::table('provinces')->pluck('id')->toArray();

$district_arr = DB::table('districts')->pluck('id')
     ->whereIn('province_id', $province_arr)->toArray();
```

But `$district_arr` is always empty. (i.e. `dd($district_arr)` always give `[]`)

Database contains data to match the query. Can someone help me figure out why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pluck` AFTER `whereIn` like so:

```
$district_arr = DB::table('districts')->whereIn('province_id', $province_arr)
    ->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

because `pluck` is here the method that gets data from database. If you add condition after getting from database you are not getting what you expected.

Otherwise you get data from database and then you run `whereIn` on [Support Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) and there are no records with `province_id` because all of them have only `id` as you specified in `pluck`

Comment: Thank you a lot. I spent hours to figure out why it doesn't work. But I couldn't see this mistake. Thank you again (Y)

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne You're welcome. It's easy to miss it